Issues with Amazon CloudFront Returning 403 Errors
I'm currently facing an issue with setting up Amazon CloudFront for my Rails API hosted on Render.com. I've configured the CloudFront distribution and linked it to my API, but when I try to access the API endpoint through CloudFront, I receive a 403 error with the message: "The request could not be satisfied."
Here are some details about my setup:

Origin Server: Hosted on Render.com, accessible at project-api.onrender.com.

CloudFront Distribution: Set up with multiple origins, including api.example.ma.

CORS Configuration: CORS is set up to allow all origins (*).

Domains Allowed: In Rails, I have allowed the domains on config like that :

project-api.onrender.com

infra.example.ma

api.example.ma

example.cloudfront.net




I've already verified that my SSL certificates are valid, and the origin server can be accessed directly without any issues. I've also reviewed the CloudFront documentation and tried various troubleshooting steps, including checking the CORS settings, ensuring that the Origin Protocol Policy is set correctly, and looking into the server and CloudFront logs. Despite these efforts, the issue persists.
Questions:

What could be the potential reasons for receiving a 403 error when accessing the API through CloudFront?

Are there specific CloudFront settings or configurations I might be missing?

Could this issue be related to network or firewall settings, and if so, how can I diagnose it?


Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

nope i don't have it  @dbugger
